# Adding a count/tally to an array of hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

Say I have a list of items with prices like this:

```
[{:dog=>3.0}, {:cat=>5.0},{:dog=>3.0}]
```

how could i collate the dog hashes as they are the same, and maybe produce something like this:

```
[{:dog=>6.0},{:cat=>5.0}]
```

or (it may be clearer to have something like this):

```
[{tally=>2, :dog=>3.0}, {tally=>1, :cat=>5.0}]
```

Comment: If you're "grouping" the hashes by their keys, do you really need to have an array of hashes? (where as I see, no hash has the same keys).

Comment: The tally version, should be `:dog => 3.0` or `:dog => 6.0` (adding them)?